# feedparser and Google News

Tags: python, rss, feedparser, google-news

I'm trying to download a corpus of news (to try to do some natural language processing) from Google News using the universal feedparser with python. I really know nothing of XML, I'm just using an example of how to use the feedparser.
The problem is that I can't find in the dict I get from the RSS feed the *content* of the news just the title.

The code I'm currently trying to use is this:

```
import feedparser
url = 'http://news.google.com.br/news?pz=1&cf=all&ned=us&hl=en&output=rss' 
# just some GNews feed - I'll use a specific search later

feed = feedparser.parse(url)
for post in feed.entries:
   print post.title
   print post.keys()
```

The keys I get in this post are just the title, summary, date, etc... there's no content.

Is this some issue with Google News or am I doing anything wrong? Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Google news doesn't store the actual content a far as I know, just a summary to the content. You will need to scrape the site it links to for the content.

Comment: :(

I just realized that this is true of almost every relevant news source  worldwide. The RSS feed never contain the full text of the news, just the summary. I think I'll have to learn how to use BeautifulSoup.

Comment: I just realized how to parse some pages with BeautifulSoup. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you examined the feed from Google News?

There is a root element in each feed which contains a bunch of information and the actual entries dict. Here's a dirty way to see what's available:

```
import feedparser
d = feedparser.parse('http://news.google.com/news?pz=1&cf=all&ned=ca&hl=en&topic=w&output=rss')

print [field for field in d]
```

From what we can see we have an `entries` field which most likely contains .. news entries! If you:

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(entry for entry in d['entries'])
```

We get some more information :) That will show you all the fields related to each entry in a pretty printed manner (that's what pprint is for)

So, to fetch all the titles of our news entries from this feed:

```
titles = [entry.title for entry in d['entries']
```

so, play around with that. Hopefully that's a helpful start

Comment: Humm... I played around with this a bit. Apparently this rss give only a summary, not the full text of the news. :(

Answer (score 1):

First you need to check out [RSS Specification](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html).  And here is a [feed parser](http://www.feedparser.org/).  That should get you started.